# Streaming is failing in Mule when I use DataWeave functions for a large file

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I'm reading a large excel file using `streaming` (Repeatable file store) in file listener component and also `deferred=true` under DataWeave script to send the streamed data to next components.
I'm using `orderBy` and `groupBy`, but it fails with memory issue.
File size is around 5 GB.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json deferred=true
...
(payload orderBy $.fname) groupBy $.mark pluck $
```

Is there a better way to sort and group in DataWeave ?

Comment: Share the error and the file connector configuration & operation. Have you generated a heap dump and analyzed it?

Comment: There's a typo: groubBy = groupBy

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is that some dataweave functions are not capable of streaming. In this case, `orderBy` and `groupBy` both require the entire input in order to do their jobs.

You can use the [@StreamCapable](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-streaming#validate-a-script-for-streamed-data-experimental-feature) directive to make sure your dataweave code works with streaming, by declaring your `input` at the top like so:

```
@StreamCapable
input payload application/xlsx
```

You also need to make sure your file listener is set up with a [streaming reader](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-excel#example3) with `outputMimeType="application/xlsx; streaming=true"`.

Comment: Adding that will show a message that explain that the script is not stream capable: `Parameter payload is not stream capable.
Reasons:
 - Invoking a function whose parameter is not StreamCapable. at 
6| (payload orderBy $.fname) groupBy $.mark pluck $`

Comment: Yes, this is the purpose. Then you can rewrite your dataweave expression in a way that is compatible with streaming.

Comment: I was just clarifying for readers of the answer.